# auto-initializing and const correctness

Tags: c++

I have a custom iterator implementation (it iterates over a db query result, but that is irrelevant to this). It conceptually has 2 sets of functions: `get` type functions, which return a value from the current item (current row), and `setup` type functions (in my case `bind`s), which set up the iterator before it starts the iteration, so a new iterator instance is actually not pointing to the first item yet. There is also a `reset` function that nullifies the iterator and readys for being setup differently.

When one of the `get` functions is called, it first checks if the iterator is still new or has been reset (effectively pointing to `begin()-1`) and if so, advances it to the first item. The `get` functions would (should) be `const`, except that that conditional first advancement prevents this.

Should I:

1. Declare them `const` and throw in a `mutable` for the isReset flag, or
2. Leave it as is, and accept the fact that under-the-hood initializing the object makes it non-`const`, or
3. Replace the self-initializing with a check for initialized state, and leave it up to the user to call `operator++` once before calling any of the `get` functions?

Comment: A fresh iterator on which no `get...` has been called can be equal to `end()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterator has state (i.e. whether or not underlying data is available yet), and the "get" function alters that state. So that makes it just like any other iterator. The "get" function shouldn't be const. By the way, instead of calling your function "get", it would be better to make the iterator have the same interface as Standard Library iterators - then you can use standard algorithms on it. So use the operator*() and operator++() functions among others.

Comment: I do use the operator++(). As for the operator*(), the get functions also take a column parameter, and there are different ones for getting different types (getInt(), getString(), etc.), so that is not so simple.

Comment: I see your point about the different types of get. I'm wondering if it's best for operator*() to return some kind of "Record" or "Row" class which has the necessary get*(n) functions.

Comment: You might want to see how other people have solved this; for example sqlpp11 - https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11